# Why does the TextRange.InsertSymbol method replace the text in my TextRange?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

In the process of generating a slide via VBA in powerpoint, I need to insert a "Wingdings symbol" within a generated text which is a comparison of two values. I made this method which is working exactly as I want

```
Sub formatDifference(header As String, old As Integer, now As Integer, txt As TextRange)
    Dim diff As Integer
    diff = old - now

    With txt
        If (diff > 0) Then
            .InsertSymbol "Wingdings", getArrowCharCode("down")
                                       ' getArrowCharCode is a custom function to get the 
                                       ' char code as an Integer
        ElseIf (diff = 0) Then
            .InsertSymbol "Wingdings", getArrowCharCode("right")
        Else
            .InsertSymbol "Wingdings", getArrowCharCode("up")
        End If

        .InsertBefore header & now & " ("    ' <-- note this line
        .InsertAfter " " & Abs(diff) & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

The `formatDifference` Sub is basically just adding a bullet point line in the text (in the example below, the procedure is called 4 times before I add a non-bullet text).

What I don't understand is when I initiate the text with some text and then use the `InsertSymbol` method, the text seems to actually get replaced instead of having the symbol appended at the end. Here's an example of the different code :

```
Sub formatDifference(header As String, old As Integer, now As Integer, txt As TextRange)
    Dim diff As Integer
    diff = old - now

    With txt
        .InsertAfter header & now & " (" ' <-- line moved here
                                         '     it doesn't matter if I use 
                                         '     .Text = "initial text"', 
                                         '     it will do the same thing
        If (diff > 0) Then
            .InsertSymbol "Wingdings", getArrowCharCode("down")
        ElseIf (diff = 0) Then
            .InsertSymbol "Wingdings", getArrowCharCode("right")
        Else
            .InsertSymbol "Wingdings", getArrowCharCode("up")
        End If
        .InsertAfter " " & Abs(diff) & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

And here's a comparison of the two results I get from the codes above (in the same order) :

[image: Example of the difference the codes make]

My understanding of the `InsertSymbol` method was that it would insert the symbol at the end of the last paragraph, but it does not look like it... Is my second example faulty or did I misunderstand the [description of the method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.insertsymbol)?

---

**P.S. Note**: the header parameter was holding the carriage return and line feed characters which is why the second capture has all the points on the same line since that first part seems to be replaced.

Comment: Seems like `InsertSymbol` for PowerPoint works like the implementation for [Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertsymbol), where you have to collapse the range, if you don't want to get it replaced. Collapse the TextRange to its end with `Set txt = txt.Characters(txt.Characters.Count + 1)` before `txt.InsertSymbol()`.

Comment: @asger if you could make an answer out of your comment, I'd be glad to give you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Documentation of InsertSymbol implementations

Microsoft Word's [Range.InsertSymbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertsymbol) and [Selection.InsertSymbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertsymbol) implementations are described as:

> Inserts a symbol in place of the specified range.
> If you don't want to replace the range, use the Collapse method before you use this method.

Microsoft Publisher's [TextRange.InsertSymbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/publisher.textrange.insertsymbol) implementation is described as:

> Returns a TextRange object that represents a symbol inserted in place of the specified range or selection.
> If you do not want to replace the range or selection, use the Collapse method before you use this method.

And then there are Office [TextRange2.InsertSymbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.textrange2.insertsymbol) and PowerPoint [TextRange2.InsertSymbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange2.insertsymbol) methods described as:

> Inserts a symbol from the specified font set into the range of text represented by the TextRange2 object.

With this in mind, the PowerPoint documentation of the [TextRange.InsertSymbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.textrange.insertsymbol) implementation is a bit *inaccurate* including a **wrong** explanation ("after the first sentence") of the included code example.

## InsertSymbol *after* TextRange

If you want to get the symbol inserted after the provided `TextRange`, I suggest following wrapper function:

```
Public Function InsertSymbolAfter(newTextRange As PowerPoint.TextRange, _
                           newFontName As String, _
                           newCharNumber As Long, _
                           Optional newUnicode As MsoTriState = msoFalse) As TextRange

    If Right(newTextRange.Text, 1) = vbCr Then
        Set InsertSymbolAfter = newTextRange.Characters(newTextRange.Characters.Count) _
            .InsertSymbol(newFontName, newCharNumber, newUnicode)
        newTextRange.InsertAfter vbCr
    Else
        Set newTextRange = newTextRange.InsertAfter("#")
        Set InsertSymbolAfter = newTextRange _
            .InsertSymbol(newFontName, newCharNumber, newUnicode)
    End If

End Function
```

It distinguishes two cases:

- If the last character is a `vbCR` (`Chr(13)`, carriage return, CR), the symbol is added before the CR (the CR is replaced by the new symbol and added afterwards again).
- In all other cases, an arbitrary character is added first and then replaced by the new symbol.

## Test

The function can be tested for whole textframes, paragraphs or characters by this:

```
Private Sub testit()
    Const WingDingsLeft As Long = 231
    Const WingDingsRight As Long = 232
    Const WingDingsUp As Long = 233
    Const WingDingsDown As Long = 234
        
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame
        InsertSymbolAfter(.TextRange, "Wingdings", WingDingsUp)
        InsertSymbolAfter(.TextRange.Paragraphs(1), "Wingdings", WingDingsDown)
        InsertSymbolAfter(.TextRange.Characters(2, 1), "Wingdings", WingDingsRight)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I could make a workaround which seems to be working fine.

```
Sub AppendSymbol(ByRef orig As TextRange, ByVal fontName As String, ByVal charCode As Integer, Optional ByVal position As Integer = -1)
    Dim strStart, strEnd As String

    If ((position < 0) Or (position >= Len(orig.text))) Then
        orig.Paragraphs(orig.Paragraphs.Count + 1).InsertSymbol fontName, charCode
        'this one just inserts the symbol at the end by forcing a new paragraph
    Else
        strStart = Left(orig.text, position)
        strEnd = Right(orig.text, Len(orig.text) - position)

        orig.Paragraphs(1).InsertSymbol fontName, charCode
        orig.InsertBefore strStart
        orig.InsertAfter strEnd
    End If
End Function
```

In that sub, I basically copy the original line, replace it with the symbol and then re-append the string around the symbol.

I can now call that Sub like this :

```
Private Sub displayTotal(ByRef para As TextRange, ByVal prevCompare As Testing)
    Dim arrowDirection As String
    Dim tempDifference As Integer

    tempDifference = p_total - prevCompare.Total
    para.InsertAfter "Number of elements : " & p_total & " ("

    'calling the Sub
    AppendSymbol para, "Wingdings", getWingdingArrowChar(getArrowDirection(tempDifference))

    para.InsertAfter " " & Abs(tempDifference) & ")"
    para.IndentLevel = 2
    para.ParagraphFormat.Bullet = msoFalse
End Sub
```

---

As for the explanation, [Asger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10908769/asger) seems to be on to something. The implementation of the method, apparently similar to Word's, would need the text range to collapse before it can add a symbol.

In the custom method above, the line `orig.Paragraphs(orig.Paragraphs.Count + 1).InsertSymbol fontName, charCode` is basically forcing the current paragraph to collapse by adding a paragraph after it, which is why the `InsertSybol` method then works as expected.